# Django, Nginx weird behaviour of urls.py

Tags: python, django, docker, nginx, django-rest-framework

Im developing and API using Django and django-rest-framework.

I have a linux server running Ubuntu, there is installed Docker and Nginx, Im running Django App with Postgresql database in docker container. Server's nginx is exposing port 443 and tunneling this to docker via unix socket.

Everything seems to be okay. But the part in project-level `urls.py` is driving me crazy past five hours.

My app level `urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from devices.viewsets import *
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'endpoint1', Endpoint1ViewSet, base_name='user')
router.register(r'users', UsersViewSet, base_name='device')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Project-level `urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls

API_PREFIX = 'api/v1/'

urlpatterns = [
    url(API_PREFIX + 'docs/', include_docs_urls(title='API Docs')),
    url(API_PREFIX + 'admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(API_PREFIX, include('devices.urls')) # This line is killing me
]
```

Nginx part:

```
  # API
    location /api/v1 {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/var/run/api/app.sock;
    }

    location /api/v1/static {
        rewrite /api/v1/static/(.*) /$1 break;
        root /home/ubuntu/device_api/api/v1/static;

    }
```

So far I launch the container with docker-compose, and i can acces `https://myweb.com/api/v1/docs`, `https://myweb.com/api/v1/admin`

but the API endpoints itselfs seems hidden somewhere, because when i try to request `https://myweb.com/api/v1/users` i get nginx 502 and in `docker-compose logs | grep api` gives me this output:

```
 django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "api_user" does not exist
api          | LINE 1: ..., "api_user"."note", "api_user"."company_id" FROM "api_user"
```

That seems like it is trying to access `/users/api/v1` maybe? Thats very strange, because the root of API, `https://myweb.com/api/v1/` gives me default `django-rest-framework` page with all accessible endpoints, however, they dont work.

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "users": "https://myweb.com/api/v1/users/",
    "devices": "https://myweb.com/api/v1/devices/",   
}
```

I've tried pretty much anything and I'm really out of ideas, any help is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:
For those wondering, changing `url` to `path` doesnt work either.

EDIT2: Added project structure

```
device_api
├── device_api
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── device_api.service
├── devices
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── serializers.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── viewsets.py
│   └── views.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── manage.py
├── requirements.txt
└── uwsgi.ini
```

EDIT3:
When i change project-level `urls.py` as following:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(API_PREFIX + 'docs/', include_docs_urls(title='API Docs')),
    url(API_PREFIX + 'admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(API_PREFIX, include('devices.urls')) # This line is killing me
]
```

The output of request to `https://myweb.com/api/v1/users` results in Django 404 with following possible routes:

```
api/v1/docs/
api/v1/admin/
api/v1/ ^users/$ [name='user-list']
api/v1/ ^users\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='user-list']
api/v1/ ^users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='user-detail']
api/v1/ ^users/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='user-detail']
api/v1/ ^devices/$ [name='device-list']
api/v1/ ^devices\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='device-list']
api/v1/ ^devices/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$ [name='device-detail']
api/v1/ ^devices/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='device-detail']
```

Comment: Try adding `rewrite_log on;` to your nginx logs to get detailed rewrite logs and first if any rewrite is going wrong

Comment: Hello @TarunLalwani. I've just tried that but nothing interesting, I guess it is on django part

Comment: Also rewrite is hapenning only in static part. And that works just fine.

Comment: Actually re-looking at the exception, it looks like it a DB call issue somewhere? Also I assume this works without nginx? If you have not tested that part, I would suggest remove nginx and test directly

Comment: My wild guess is that it is trying to query /api/v1/usersapi/v1.

It was working directly without unix socket.

Comment: `relation "api_user" does not exist` suggests that you haven't run `./manage.py migrate` to create the table. You might also have to run `makemigrations` before `migrate`.

Comment: Hello Alasdair, thanks for your input. I've run both makemigrations and migrate. I dont even have model api_user

Comment: My model is User. Thats why im suspicious its trying to query /api/v1/usersapi

Comment: Can you try with running gunicorn on http and without nginx? In such issue you want to take each item out one by one and see where the issue has been introduced?

Comment: Thats working, im convienced that it is routing issue.

Comment: api_user is the name of relation in DB because you have app api with model User.  This is certainly NOT a routing issue but DB issue

Comment: Hello @AlexandrTatarinov. I've added project structure to my question, I do not have an app named api. It is called device_api

Comment: So,  maybe it was called api when you created that model,  that doesn't matters.  Django can't run query to DB with wrong relation name because of wrong URL,  unless you generate raw Sql from your URL manually.  So the problem should be with missing tables. Please check again your migrate and makemigrations commands and ensure you apply migrations to the same database your web app is using.

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov. It was never called API, it looks like DB error, but I dont have any table called api_users, the only possible way this could happen, is if it would query /usersapi, which might be translated by django to api_user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

The reason why it was giving me db error of unexisting table `api.user` was because of a one line in `apps.py`

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'devices'
    verbose_name = 'API Data'
    label = 'api'
```

That label variable caused Django to think that my App is called `api` instead of `devices`, so when I did `manage.py migrate` it does not created tables, even though I had devices listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Perhaps I added the label in development and did not pay too much attention to it since, well.. It is called label, who would know what impact it can do..
After renaming label with `devices` instead of `api` and executing `manage.py migrate devices`, everything started working.